# Importance of ethnicity for organ donor

Tags: ethnicity, organ-donation, race

I always wondered if the race had an influence on the chance of finding a matching organ donor.

For example, do Asian people have a better chance of finding a matching organ from searching only in the Asian population compare with searching within same amount of people but from different race group?

Comment: http://content.time.com/time/health/article/0,8599,1993074,00.html